Redux Saga pending/success/failure pattern - how to handle interruption
I am using redux-saga and @reduxjs/toolkit. I make some webservice requests and save their responses into redux, and I am following a pending/success/failure pattern I've seen mentioned in a few places. For my redux saga:
export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(actionGetData.toString(), handleGetData);
}

with my generator function:
function* handleGetData(action: any): Generator<any, any, any> {
    yield put({ type: 'ACTION.GETDATA_PENDING', payload: action.payload });
    try {
        const response = yield call(apiRequest);
        const responseData = response.data;
        yield put({ type: 'ACTION.GETDATA_FULFILLED', payload: { name: action.payload, data: responseData } });
    } catch (error: any) {
        yield put({ type: 'ACTION.GETDATA_FAILED', payload: { name: action.payload, data: error.message } });
    }
}

I save this status (pending, success, failure) into redux, and there is a visual component on the screen that corresponds to this status-- a loading animation, or a success/failure notification, etc.
This all works great, but the issue is that when this apiRequest takes a while to complete and the user prematurely cancels the request-- say, by closing the page before the webservice request returns a response. In this case, when the user reloads the page, the status is stuck in a "loading" state, except this time, no apiRequest will be made, so there is no way to exit this state with a success or failure, so a never-ending loading animation is shown to the user, and there is nothing to retry the webservice request.
How can I resolve this? Is there a way to call a cleanup function that can be executed before the function exits (e.g. immediately call the 'failed' action if the page is prematurely stopped)? Is there a way to 'watch' this 'pending' status and trigger a retry if it has been stuck for a certain amount of time?

To the close vote: This is not an opinion-based question. The bug I am trying to resolve is when the page is refreshed when the data request is pending. It will be stuck in a pending status, with no way to trigger another api request.

I see Tyler has edited/removed the subjectively qualified parts of your post, but it's still a bit too broad/open-ended. Have you tried anything specific yet? I've solved a similar issue in a previous project by tracking all active network requests using a queue. When requests settle they are removed from the queue. The Redux store was persisted to longer-term storage, e.g. localStorage, and when the app starts/mounts one of the first things it does is execute the queue. This is just one way to solve the problem, there are likely several/many solutions available at your disposal.

@DrewReese So where are you placing your call to execute the queue? I am already tracking network requests, but my problem is how to figure out when requests have been pending for too long, and e.g. time them out and fail them.

I implemented processing the queue when the app mounts, and periodically on something like a 15 minute interval. I used Redux-Toolkit-Query (with timeouts and retries), if the endpoint call was successful, then all good, but if it timed out/errored/etc I would add the request data, endpoint, etc, to the queue to be periodically processed. Pending requests are removed from queue and re-run, and if they failed they are re-added to the queue.

"but my problem is how to figure out when requests have been pending for too long, and e.g. time them out and fail them." - This depends on the library/implementation you are using to make your requests.

To solve this, I ended up adding a check for pending and rejected webservice requests to occur at the start of my root saga:
function* handlePendingRequestsSaga() {
    yield put({ type: actionClearPendingDataRequests.toString() });
    yield put({ type: actionRetryRejectedDataRequests.toString() });
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield handlePendingRequestsSaga();
    yield takeEvery(actionGetData.toString(), handleGetResource);
}

And in the corresponding reducers, the one for actionClearPendingDataRequests takes the requests that were marked pending and moves them to rejected, while the one for actionRetryRejectedDataRequests will retry the requests that were previously marked rejected. Because handlePendingRequestsSaga fires on initialization (say, when a page is refreshed or first loaded), any requests that were interrupted will be marked rejected and automatically retried, and any requests that have previously failed will also be retried (once). If those fail again without interruption, the page workflow is followed as intended (show error message to user for failed request(s), etc).
